# How do I decrease the speed of executing a function?

Tags: javascript

I know I can use `setTimeout()` to do that but my case is a little critical.
Here is an example:

```js
var nameinput = document.getElementById("typename");
var printed = document.getElementById("name");

function demo(){
setTimeout(function(){printed.innerHTML = nameinput.value.toLowerCase()}, 800);
  }

nameinput.addEventListener("input", demo);
```

```css
#name {
    height: 50px;
    width: 400px;
    margin: 20px auto;
    border: 1px solid lightgreen;
    border-radius: 4px;
    font-family: monospace;
    font-size: 200%;
    font-weight: 100;
    line-height: 50px;    
}

#typename {
    font-size: 150%;
    line-height: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    width: 30%;
    min-width: 350px;
    border: 1px solid skyblue;
    display: block;
    margin: 20px auto;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div id="name"></div>
<p>some text</p>
<input id="typename" type="text"/>
```

The code I provided above takes my text as an input and prints it after the specified delay, but it works only if I wait till that time after each letter input.

In a word, I want it to work like:
"I can type a word in 0.8 sec, but it will type each of the letters after 0.8 sec of delay per letter"

Comment: This is a little hard to get, but do you want a *continuous* delay, so when you type a character, it shows up exactly 0.8 seconds after you've typed it, and doesn't wait for the next character etc.

Comment: *"each letter will be printed after the specified time period"* I believe the problem is that you are getting the current input value *after* the timeout instead of before. You should get the value when the key is pressed, not after the timeout. That's because you will have typed multiple characters between each timeouts.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/y0rtf8xd/1/

Comment: @adeneo do you think each letters are being printed after the specified 0.8 sec delay ? I mean try increasing the delay and see.

Comment: @Towkir: I guess it's unclear what you are trying to achieve. Do you want the letters to appear 0.8 seconds after they have been *typed* or do you want  each of them to appear 0.8 seconds after *the previous letter appeared*? These are two different things.

Comment: Seems to work perfectly fine for me -> https://jsfiddle.net/y0rtf8xd/3/ ... if that's not what you want, how about trying to explain exactly *what it is* you want ?

Comment: the delay gets applied for each letter, simple. question was updated. see the bottom 3rd paragraph of the question :)

Comment: So what you want is some sort of queue, where there's always at least 0.8 seconds between each character appearing, regardless of how fast they are being typed.

Comment: The delay **is** applied to each letter. But if you type a letter every 100ms, there will also only be a 100ms delay between the letters in the mirrored output.

Comment: @adeneo exactly :)

Comment: *"do you want each of them to appear 0.8 seconds after the previous letter appeared?"* --> yes.

Comment: @FelixKling yes, that is what I want

Comment: Please [edit] your question to clarify that.

Comment: Guys, how about making an array of letters for that string and apply the delay to each last item of that array ?

Comment: @Towkir see my answer and check if that's what you want.

Comment: @Azamantes thanks for your effort, but that is not actually the thing, you made it in the input field, I wanted it on another div, see the snippet I provided. Thanks, 
And I don't know why do people always downvotes questions :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to capture each change in an array, try this:

```js
var nameinput = document.getElementById("typename");
var printed = document.getElementById("name");

var actions = []

function demo() {
  var old = actions.length ?
      actions[actions.length - 1].old : printed.innerHTML
  var str = nameinput.value.toLowerCase()

  if (old.length < str.length)
    actions.push({
      f: add.bind(null, str.slice(-1)),
      old: str
    })
  else if (old.length > str.length)
    actions.push({
      f: del,
      old: str
    })
 }

function play() {
  if (!actions.length)
    return
    
  var a = actions.shift()
  a.f()
}

function add(s) {
  printed.innerHTML += s
}

function del() {
  printed.innerHTML = printed.innerHTML.slice(0, printed.innerHTML.length - 1)
}

setInterval(play, 800)
nameinput.addEventListener("input", demo);
```

```css
#name {
  height: 50px;
  width: 400px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  border: 1px solid lightgreen;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 200%;
  font-weight: 100;
  line-height: 50px;
}
#typename {
  font-size: 150%;
  line-height: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  width: 30%;
  min-width: 350px;
  border: 1px solid skyblue;
  display: block;
  margin: 20px auto;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div id="name"></div>
<p>some text</p>
<input id="typename" type="text" />
```

this is just a test, seems to work, but may have some flaws somewhere.

Comment: OP wanted to queue the letters and update one after the other at 0.8sec interval

Comment: @AndrewLi no it does not, I wanted each letters to wait for a time of 0.8 sec,  you can see it increasing the delay.   the delay just gets applied for the first letter, and then does it quickly

Answer (score 1):

Here's my take at this. It clears the existing text if the current output is not a substring of the input value.

Wrapped everything inside a single variable, to avoid name collisions with any existing scripts and added some controls so it's easier to implement.

```js
var iO = {
    interval: 800,
    inputSelector: '#input',
    outputSelector: '#output',
    
    updating: false,
    start: function () {
        iO.updating ||
        (   iO.updating = setInterval(iO.update, iO.interval),
                iO.update()
        )
    },
    stop: function () {
        clearInterval(iO.updating);
        iO.updating = false
    },
    update: function () {
        var i = document.querySelector(iO.inputSelector),
            o = document.querySelector(iO.outputSelector),
            $in = i.value,
            $out = o.innerHTML;
        if ($out == $in) {
            // update finished. stop.
            iO.stop();
            return
        }
        if (!$in.length) {
            // no input. clear output. stop.
            o.innerHTML = '';
            iO.stop();
            return
        }
        if ($out.length > $in.length || $in.indexOf($out) == -1) {
            // output > input or output not found in input. clear output.
            o.innerHTML = '';
        }
        if (typeof $in[$out.length] !== "undefined") {
            // next letter is defined. add it to output.
            o.innerHTML += $in[$out.length];
        }
        if (o.innerHTML == $in) {
            // update finished. stop.
            iO.stop();
        }
    }
};

document.getElementById("input").addEventListener("keyup", iO.start);
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#input, #output {
  font-size: 2.1rem;
  line-height: 2.1rem;
  min-height: 4rem;
  min-width: calc(100vw - 6rem);
  max-width: 80vw;
  margin: 2rem auto 1rem;
  display: block;
  line-height: 2rem;
  padding: .5rem 1rem;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#output {
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 2px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.1),0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.07),0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0,0,0,.06);
  min-height: 10rem;
  padding: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<input id="input" type="text" />
<div id="output"></div>
```

Answer (score -2):

You want to create a closure with the input at the time of the user's input:

```
function demo(){
    setTimeout(
        function(inp){
            return function(){
                printed.innerHTML = inp;
            }
    }(nameinput.value.toLowerCase()), 800);
}
```

This stores a closure to be executed **with the input at the moment of setting the timeout**. I think that's what you expect.

Comment: That's unnecessarily complex. Just do `function demo() { var value = this.value; setTimeout(function() { printed.innerHTML = value; }, 800); }`.

Comment: How is it more complex? I'm not a javascript expert, just don't see the big difference.

Comment: I'd say that using an IIFE is more complex than not using one. Also, the function passed to `setTimeout` is already a closure. There really isn't a need to introduce more functions.

Comment: Well, that's an opinion... I find it pretty natural in functional programming languages, like javascript...

Comment: *you want to create a closure* - I'm not sure someone with a basic knowledge of JS (the OP) wants something as complex as this (as they probably won't understand) when there are easier options.

Comment: If you want to avoid to declare a variable, ok. But to put this a bit into perspective, you are suggesting to do `(function(a) { return a; }(42)) + 1` when you could just do `var a = 42; a + 1`.

Comment: @FelixKling what you're suggesting obviously would not work, you have to bind the variable in the **outer** scope as you suggested in your eraelier comment. So no, that's **not** what I'm suggesting.

Comment: It was just an example of an unnecessary function call ;)

Comment: @FelixKling I think my answer is more obvious to anyone used to functional programming languages while your answer is more obvious to anyone used to javascript. Could be wrong.